# Imported CSV is missing fields

Tags: php, mysql, csv, yii, load-data-infile

I have to import a CSV file to MySQL from Yii. This is my query:

```
$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".addslashes($dir)."'
        INTO TABLE `card`
        FIELDS
        TERMINATED BY ','
        ENCLOSED BY '\"'
        LINES
        TERMINATED BY '\n'
        IGNORE 1 LINES
        (`ID_CARD`,`SERIAL_NO`,`SERIAL_NO_CARD`,`ICCID`,`MSISDN`,`SITE_NAME`,`STATUS`,`DATE_HISTORY`)";
Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->execute();
```

However, only column `ID_CARD` was inserted.

What am I doing wrong?

I already tested this on PHPMyAdmin but it did the same thing.

[image: example data]

Comment: Maybe you can provide a sample of your input data. It could be possible, that there is a " inside your fields. Eventually you need to change the terminator or enclosure sign

Comment: Could you please add these three lines as raw data csv? Even though, which Spreadsheet application are you using?

Comment: @DennisMeissner how can i add these three lines as raw data csv? save them as csv? btw, i use libreoffice.

Comment: Just open your xyz.csv file with a text editor and then paste it here please. I assume, that you don't have any enclosure in your csv.

Comment: @DennisMeissner this is my file


ID_CARD  SERIAL_NO SERIAL_NO_CARD ICCID MSISDN SITE_NAME STATUS DATE_HISTORY
SIMCARD/0003/2014 987654 987655 23456 67890 SMU Arrival 2014-05-12
SIMCARD/0004/2014 87654321 876543 2345678 3456789 SMU Arrival 2014-05-13

Comment: @DennisMeissner i think u're right, something wrong with my csv file, so i googling about it, and i found it, my csv file not have ',' which separate each column... thank you by the way :)

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'test.csv' 
INTO TABLE card FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1
LINES (ID_CARD,SERIAL_NO,SERIAL_NO_CARD,ICCID,MSISDN,SITE_NAME,STATUS,DATE_HISTORY)
```